# Why is there no php-gd packages available on alpine 3.4/3.5/3.6?

Tags: alpine-linux

It seems it was only available in alpine 3.3?

What is the reason it would not be available in later versions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the package name changed: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/php7-gd